# How does NFT marketplaces like OpenSea deal with transactions when the transfer function doesn't check if the buyer already pays the price

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

I'm new to NFT trading. I feel confused when studying the example contract of OpenSea (OpenSea creature). Maybe it's because I didn't correctly understand the working procedure of it.

So the biggest question is that I didn't find any code about checking whether the buyer has paid the price in those transfer functions. Assuming A lists some NFT arts on OpenSea and B pays to buy it, shouldn't the smart contract runs like this: receive B's cryptocurrency and then transfer the token to B?

Or maybe the whole procedure contains off-chain parts that deal with these functions? In that case, OpenSea becomes a trusted third party (or intermediary) and the ownership of NFT and cryptocurrency all go through it. And it makes OpenSea kind of centralized?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the contracts?

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7dca125b1e805dc88814aed7ccc810f677d3e1db
This is a deployed contract on Rinkeby.